# CSS - Column like flex box with dynamic content

Tags: html, jquery, css, flexbox

I am using [jQuery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) to make suggestions for a user input. I always have a buidling description and for some of them I also have a shortcut. Both of them are in a `div` and this is one suggestion from the form. The length of both is dynamically. I thought `display: flex;` is a good start. But i face two major issues.

1. If i have a very long description, the suggestion container gets bigger as the actual input field (both of them should have the same width)
2. The description should have the same alignment, regardless of wheather I have a shortcut for this building or not.

I used `justify-content: space-between;` for the spacing. But the float from the last flex element is on the right. This looks kinda ugly, I want to align them left.

I wonder if it´s possible to do this with a flexbox.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7d4yzoa5/) to illustrate my problem. (type *buil* to trigger the autocomplete)

If the description is too long, the font-size should be reduced automatically, also a linke break is okay.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<body>

<div class="search_box">
<form autocomplete="off">
<div class="autocomplete">
  <input type="text" id="nameSearch" class="nameSearch" placeholder="Suche">
</div>
</form>
</div>

<script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.search_box {
    width: 380px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 20px;
    top: 94px;
    z-index: 20000;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(26, 45, 51, 0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;

}


.nameSearch {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    text-indent: 50px;
    color: #2d4a59;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: solid 1px rgba(45, 74, 89, 0.5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
}



.ui-autocomplete {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial sans-serif;
  color: #2d4a59;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: solid 1px rgba(45, 74, 89, 0.5);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(26, 45, 51, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(26, 45, 51, 0.3);
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


.ui-autocomplete > li > div{
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 43px;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: Arial;
}


.ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper:hover, .ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active {
    background-color: #278096;
    color: white;
    border: none;
}


.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

.ui-autocomplete > .each > .acItem {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 12px 43px;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 100%;
}

.label {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var projects = [
        {
            "short": "AB 123",
            "long": "Building A"
        },
        {
            "short": "",
            "long": "Building with no ID"
        },
        {
            "short": "AAAAA",
            "long": "Building with 5 ID digits"
        },
        {
            "short": "AB",
            "long": "This building has a very very very very very very very very long name"
        },
        {
            "short": "A1",
            "long": "short name"
        }
    ]

    function lightwell(request, response) {
        function hasMatch(s) {
            return s.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase())!==-1;
        }
        var i, l, obj, matches = [];

        if (request.term==="") {
            response([]);
            return;
        }

        for  (i = 0, l = projects.length; i<l; i++) {
            obj = projects[i];
            console.log(obj);
            if (hasMatch(obj.short) || hasMatch(obj.long)) {
                matches.push(obj);
            }
        }
        response(matches);
    }

    $( "#nameSearch" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: lightwell,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#nameSearch" ).val( ui.item.short );
            return false;
        },

    })

    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $("<li class='each'>")
            .append("<div class='acItem'>" +
                "<span class='label'>" + item.short + "</span>" +
                "<span class='long'>" + item.long + "</span>" +
                "</div>")

            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

Comment: why not use css-grid then. if you need to control width and height within a row or column css-grid is the better solution over flexbox.